# Abysmal Skype audio on Asus Fonepad 8

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, audio, skype

I bought a new Asus Fonepad 8 for a friend. It works great, and the sound is crystal clear.

The only exception is Skype - all calls sound perfect on the receiving end, but on the Fonepad everything sounds like through a phone! The audio quality is consistently awful.

We've tried different Wi-Fi networks and people to call (including the Skype test call, which sounds as bad).

Skype was the main reason for buying the tablet, so this really hurts. What can I do to try and fix this?

The Fonepad is running Android 4.4.2.